# Rspec test on Simple Form Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, simple-form

I am trying to run a request spec on a form (built with Simple Form).  The form includes some select boxes that are generated using the association method and therefore database values for the model.

When running save_and_open_page it doesn't look like the select the values in the drop downs.

I have looked at Mocking and Stubbing but this is new to me and I'm still a little confused on the concept beyond basic usage.

Is there any way to generate the collection for the select box so Capybara can pick it up?

I'm using Rails 3.1, Simple Form, Capybara and FactoryGirl.

My code is...

**challenge_spec**

```
describe "New Challenges" do

  before(:all) do
    %w["Under 13", "13 - 16"].each do |item|
      FactoryGirl.create(:age, :name => item)
     end
  end

  it "should redirect to resources after submission" do

    login_valid_user

    visit new_challenge_path

    @challenge = Factory.build(:challenge)

    fill_in "challenge_name", :with => @challenge.name
    fill_in "challenge_description", :with => @challenge.description
    fill_in "challenge_description", :with => @challenge.description
    select "30 mins", :from => "challenge_timescale"
    save_and_open_page
    select 1, :from => "challenge_age_id"
    select @challenge.category, :from => "challenge_category_id"

    click_button "save_button"

  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
def new
  @challenge = Challenge.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.haml
    format.json { render json: @challenge }
  end
end
```

**Form item**

```
<%= f.association :age, :prompt => "Please select..." %>
```

**Models**

Challenge

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :age
end
```

Age

```
class Age < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :challenges
end
```

Comment: What are the label names of your select fields? Have you tried using those instead of the actual field names.  Eg `select "30 mins", :from => "Challenge Timescale"`.

Comment: @nmott Having the same problem. I am specifically checking for the label on each of the options. When I run the page in browser, everything appears correctly. When I run in capybara, it doesn't show up in `page.html`

Comment: @Drew will need to see more detail in order to help. Can you create a new question and post link back to here and I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend creating fixtures for your tests.

This way you can manually create and manipulate the records needed for tests. It's not as efficient or elegant as using mocks, stubs and doubles but it reinforces understanding of the application and tests.